# Using ng2- libraries in --prod build throws "Unexpected value... Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation"

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular5

I'm running an Angular 5 application on Angular CLI v1.6.3. I need to use a library called `ng2-img-map` since it's the only working solution for one of the issues. However when I run `ng build --prod` it throws.

```
ERROR in : Unexpected value 'ImgMapComponent in C:/Users/.../node_modules/ng2-img-map/ng2-img-map.d.ts' declared by the module 'AppModule in C:/Users/.../src/app/app.module.ts'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.
```

When I run only `ng build` it works without a problem.

I've noticed this happens with other `ng2-` libraries which haven't been updated in a year or so. I simply use something else, however I don't have options/time for this one.

Is there any way I can fix/bypass this and use the library in `--prod` mode?

Comment: are you using webpack?

Comment: @LucaTaccagni he doesn't, angular-cli does

Comment: remove aot, ng build --prod --aot=false

Comment: @DanielNetzer I think the problem is that the OP wants to have all the good things + using the library he likes. The problem is that AOT is so restrictive (and it is for good) that all the libraries that do not / did not target the AOT in the past will most likely not pass its checks. OP: you won't find any options here. Either tweak the library or disable some parts of the prod build

Comment: as I said he can remove the AOT property from his compilation but the size of the app will be much bigger, and that's true lots of lib's are useless cause of AOT incompatibility.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I guess I'll have to disable AOT for now.

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your tsconfig.json adding a declaration:

```js
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ],
    "declaration": [
      "pathToYourFile.d.ts"
    ]
  }
}
```